# What should be change in the "gender" part of the coding I have done below?

Tags: c

In the code below keeps on looping where entering `1` will lead in the `void main()` function and inside it, there is "gender" information. However, the gender output always got skipped over right after I type the date.

The `"Enter your gender(Male/Female): "` part got skipped

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void entry() {
    FILE *fpointer;
    char name[20], gender[20], op, option;
    int visit_ID, phone_number, service_needed, change_service, date;
    float service_fee, payment_made, changes, change_service_fee;

    printf("\n\nEnter information:\n");
    printf("\nEnter name: ");
    scanf("%s", name);
    printf("\n\nEnter your ID number(Number only): ");
    scanf("%d", &visit_ID);
    printf("\n\nEnter today date in dd-mm-yy: ");
    scanf("%d", &date);
    printf("\n\nEnter your gender(Male/Female): ");
    scanf("%s", &gender);
    printf("\n\nEnter your phone number: ");
    scanf("%d", &phone_number);
    printf("\n\nDone registered\n\n");

    if ((fpointer = fopen("visitdetails.txt", "a")) == NULL) {
        perror("Write");
        exit(1);
    }
    fprintf(fpointer, "Visit ID = %d", visit_ID);
    fprintf(fpointer, "\nCustomer name = %s", name);
    fprintf(fpointer, "\nLast visit date : %d", date);
    fprintf(fpointer, "\nLast Service type repaired: %d", service_needed);
    fscanf(fpointer, "%d", service_needed);
    fprintf(fpointer, "\nLast Service fee: %.2f", service_fee);
    fprintf(fpointer, "\nLast payment: %.2f", payment_made);
    printf("\n\nRecord Written Successfully\n\n!!!");
    fclose(fpointer);
}

void Repair() {
    char name[20], gender[20], op, option;
    int visit_ID, phone_number, service_needed, date;
    float service_fee, payment_made, changes, change_service_fee;
    FILE *Welcome;

    Welcome = fopen("visitdetails.txt", "r");
    printf("\nWhich service type do you need(1-8)? ");
    scanf("%d", &service_needed);

    switch (service_needed) {
      case 1:
        printf("\nThe cost of it will be 30RM for Normal and 50RM for Urgent(type the cost): ");
        scanf("%f", &service_fee);
        break;

      case 2:
        printf("\nThe cost of it will be 40RM for Normal and 70RM for Urgent(type the cost): ");
        scanf("%f", &service_fee);
        break;

      case 3:
        printf("\nThe cost of it will be 330RM for Normal and 430RM for Urgent(type the cost): ");
        scanf("%f", &service_fee);
        break;

      case 4:
        printf("\nThe cost of it will be 160RM for Normal and 200RM for Urgent(type the cost): ");
        scanf("%f", &service_fee);
        break;

      case 5:
        printf("\nThe cost of it will be 180RM for Normal and 210RM for Urgent(type the cost): ");
        scanf("%f", &service_fee);
        break;

      case 6:
        printf("\nThe cost of it will be 50RM for Normal and 80RM for Urgent(type the cost): ", service_fee);
        scanf("%f", &service_fee);
        break;

      case 7:
        printf("\nThe cost of it will be 100RM for Normal and 150RM for Urgent(type the cost): ", service_fee);
        scanf("%f", &service_fee);
        break;

      case 8:
        printf("\nThe cost of it will be 50RM for Normal and 75RM for Urgent(type the cost): ", service_fee);
        scanf("%f", &service_fee);
        break;

      default:
        printf("Invalid option");
    }

    printf("\n\nPayment: ", payment_made);
    scanf("%f", &payment_made);

    if (payment_made > service_fee) {
        changes = payment_made - service_fee;
        printf("\nHere is your changes :%.2f\n", changes);
    }
    fclose(Welcome);
}

void Viewing_Store() {
    FILE *view;
    view = fopen("visitdetails.txt", "r");

    printf("No |    Service Type                                    | Needed Days | Service Fee | \n");
    printf("                                                                      |Normal|Urgent|\n");
    printf("1. | Remove virus,Malware, or Spyware                   |      2      | 30RM | 50RM |\n");
    printf("2. | Troubleshot and fix computer running slow          |      2      | 40RM | 70RM |\n");
    printf("3. | Laptop Screen Replacement                          |      3      | 330RM| 430RM|\n");
    printf("4. | Laptop Keyboard Replacement                        |      2      | 160RM| 200RM|\n");
    printf("5. | Laptop Battery Replacement                         |      1      | 180RM| 210RM|\n");
    printf("6. | Operating System Format and Installation           |      2      | 50RM | 80RM |\n");
    printf("7. | Data Backup and Recovery                           |      2      | 100RM| 150RM|\n");
    printf("8. | Internet Connectivity issues                       |      1      | 50RM | 75RM |\n");

    fclose(view);
}

void change_type() {
    FILE *change;
    char name[20], gender[20], op, option;
    int visit_ID, phone_number, service_needed, change_service, date;
    float service_fee, payment_made, changes, change_service_fee;

    change = fopen("visitdetails.txt", "r");
    printf("\nAre you sure you want to change the service type into(Y/N) : ", op);
    scanf("%s", &op);
    if (op == 'Y') {
        printf("\nWhat service type do you want to change into(1-8)? ", change_service);
        scanf("%d", &change_service);
        switch (change_service) {
          case 1:
            printf("\nThe cost of it will be 30RM for Normal and 50RM for Urgent(type the cost): ", change_service_fee);
            scanf("%f", &change_service_fee);
            break;

          case 2:
            printf("\nThe cost of it will be 40RM for Normal and 70RM for Urgent(type the cost): ", change_service_fee);
            scanf("%f", &change_service_fee);
            break;

          case 3:
            printf("\nThe cost of it will be 330RM for Normal and 430RM for Urgent(type the cost): ", change_service_fee);
            scanf("%f", &change_service_fee);
            break;

          case 4:
            printf("\nThe cost of it will be 160RM for Normal and 200RM for Urgent(type the cost): ", change_service_fee);
            scanf("%f", &change_service_fee);
            break;

          case 5:
            printf("\nThe cost of it will be 180RM for Normal and 210RM for Urgent(type the cost): ", change_service_fee);
            scanf("%f", &change_service_fee);
            break;

          case 6:
            printf("\nThe cost of it will be 50RM for Normal and 80RM for Urgent(type the cost): ", change_service_fee);
            scanf("%f", &change_service_fee);
            break;

          case 7:
            printf("\nThe cost of it will be 100RM for Normal and 150RM for Urgent(type the cost): ", change_service_fee);
            scanf("%f", &change_service_fee);
            break;

          case 8:
            printf("\nThe cost of it will be 50RM for Normal and 75RM for Urgent(type the cost): ", change_service_fee);
            scanf("%f", &change_service_fee);
            break;

          default:
            printf("Invalid option");
        }
    } else
    if (op == 'N') {
        printf("\nThe final price will be : %.2f", service_fee);
    }

    printf("\n\nPayment: ", payment_made);
    scanf("%f", &payment_made);

    if (payment_made > service_fee) {
        changes = payment_made - service_fee;
        printf("\nHere is your changes :%.2f\n", changes);
    } else
    if (payment_made > change_service_fee) {
        changes = payment_made - change_service_fee;
        printf("\nHere is your changes: %.2f\n", changes);
    } else
    if (payment_made == service_fee) {
        changes = payment_made - service_fee;
        printf("\nHere is your changes %f\n", changes);
    } else
    if (payment_made == change_service_fee) {
        changes = payment_made - change_service_fee;
        printf("\nHere is your changes: %f\n", changes);
    } else {
        printf("Error");
    }

    fprintf(change, "\n\nChanging service type into: %d", change_service);
    fprintf(change, "\nThe price of this service type is: %f", change_service_fee);
    fprintf(change,"\nPayment: %.2f", payment_made);
    fclose(change);
}

void any_visit(char anv[]) {
    FILE *anyvisit;
    char name[200], gender[20];
    int visit_ID, phone_number, service_needed, change_service, date, set;
    float service_fee, payment_made, changes, change_service_fee;

    anyvisit = fopen("visitdetails.txt","r");
    while (fscanf(any_visit, "%s %d %d %s %d %d\n", name, visit_ID, date, gender, phone_number, payment_made) != EOF) {
        set = strcmp(date, anv);
        if (set == 0) {
            printf("Visit_ID is %d", visit_ID);
            printf("\nName : %s", name);
            printf("\nGender is %s", gender);
            printf("\nPhone number is %d", phone_number);
            printf("\nPayment : %.2f", payment_made);
        }
    }
    fclose(anyvisit);
}

void search(char cnm[]) {
    FILE *search;
    char name[200], gender[20];
    int visit_ID, phone_number, service_needed, change_service, date, tes;
    float service_fee, payment_made, changes, change_service_fee;

    search = fopen("visitdetails.txt","r");
    while (fscanf(search, "%s %d %d %s %d %d\n", name, visit_ID, date, gender, phone_number, payment_made) != EOF) {
        tes = strcmp(name, cnm);
        if (tes == 0) {
            printf("Visit_ID is %d", visit_ID);
            printf("Date of visit is %d", date);
            printf("\nGender is %s", gender);
            printf("\nPhone number is %d", phone_number);
            printf("\nPayment: %d", date);
        }
    }
    fclose(search);
}

void main() {
    char name[200], gender[20], op, option, ch, cnm[30], anv[30];
    int visit_ID, phone_number, service_needed, change_service, date;
    float service_fee, payment_made, changes, change_service_fee;

    printf("*****Welcome to the Computer center*****\n");
    printf("\nBefore entering the store and have your equipment repair, it is best to view the store\n");
    do {
        printf("\nPress '1' to enter and have your data store");
        printf("\nPress '2' to View the store");
        printf("\nPress '3' to have your equipment being repaired");
        printf("\nPress '4' if you want to change your repair type");
        printf("\nPress '5' if you want to Search");
        printf("\nPress '6' if you want to search payment and unpaid balance by any visit");
        printf("\nPress '0' to exit");
        printf("\nEnter your choice : ");
        scanf("%d", &ch);
        switch(ch) {
          case 1:
            entry();
            break;
          case 2:
            Viewing_Store();
            break;
          case 3: 
            Repair();
            break;
          case 4:
            change_type();
            break;
          case 5:
            printf("Enter your name: ");
            scanf("%s", &cnm);
            search(cnm);
            break;
          case 6:
            printf("Enter the date you visit: ");
            scanf("%d", &anv);
            any_visit(anv);
            break;
          case 0:
            exit(0);
          default:
            printf("\nInvalid Entry!!! ");
        }
    } while (ch != 0);
}
```

Comment: You are prompting `Enter today date in dd-mm-yy` but input to `int` with `scanf("%d" ,&date);` How is that supposed to work? Should the input be to a string, which you then analyse if you need the numerical parts? You should try printing the value in `gender` (*apparently* skipped over) to see what has happened - this is basic debugging.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned above, We cannot give Gender.
Since you used **int** datatype for Storing the date, but you asked to give in **dd-mm-yy** format.

*To prove that give any "number" of int type in this prompt ***Enter today date in dd-mm-yy:*** and You can see that the program prompts for the  Gender.*

we cannot store **dd-mm-yy** this  format in **int** type.

so you can do in another ways

1. To store date as **Char** array  ***OR***
2. To store day,month,year in individual **int** variables  ***OR***
3. To use **Struct** datatype

Comment: I've tried using the second option, however it failed when inputing the data into this example:      set = strcmp(day, month, year,anv) it became error do u know the problem of it                                                                                                                     set = strcmp(date, anv);
    if(set == 0)
    {
      printf("Visit_ID is %d", visit_ID);
      printf("\nName : %s", name);
      printf("\nGender is %s", gender);
      printf("\nPhone number is %d", phone_number);
      printf("\nPayment : %.2f", payment_made);
    }
  }
  fclose(anyvisit);

Answer (score 0):

```
This is what updated from before, however the search function when pressing '5' and '6' says that segmentation fault but i can't find any wrong code in my coding. Do you mind if you check once more what is the fault @Rohith S







#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void entry()
{
      FILE * fpointer;
      char name[20], gender[20], op, option, date[50];
      int visit_ID, phone_number, service_needed, change_service;
      float service_fee, payment_made, changes, change_service_fee;


      printf("\n\nEnter information:\n");
      printf("\nEnter name: ");
      scanf("%s", name);
      printf("\n\nEnter your ID number(Number only): ");
      scanf("%d", &visit_ID);
      printf("\n\nEnter today date in dd-mm-yy: ");
      scanf("%s" ,&date);
      printf("\n\nEnter your gender(Male/Female): ");
      scanf("%s",gender);
      printf("\n\nEnter your phone number: ");
      scanf("%d", &phone_number);
      printf("\n\nDone registered\n\n");

      if((fpointer = fopen("visitdetails.txt", "a")) == NULL)
        {
          perror("Write");
              exit(1);
        }
      fprintf(fpointer, "Visit ID = %d", visit_ID);
      fprintf(fpointer, "\nCustomer name = %s", name);
      fprintf(fpointer, "\nLast visit date : %s", date);
      fprintf(fpointer,"\nLast Service type repaired: %d", service_needed);
      fscanf(fpointer,"%d",service_needed);
      fprintf(fpointer, "\nLast Service fee: %.2f",service_fee);
      fprintf(fpointer,"\nLast payment: %.2f",payment_made);
      printf("\n\nRecord Written Successfully!!!\n\n");
      fclose(fpointer);
}
void Repair()
{
      char name[20], gender[20], op, option, date[50];
      int visit_ID, phone_number,service_needed;
      float service_fee, payment_made, changes, change_service_fee;

      FILE *Welcome;
      Welcome = fopen("visitdetails.txt","r");
          printf("\nWhich service type do you need(1-8)? ");
          scanf("%d", &service_needed);

          switch(service_needed)
          {
            case 1:
                printf("\nThe cost of it will be 30RM for Normal and 50RM for Urgent(type the cost): ");
                scanf("%f", &service_fee);
                break;

            case 2:
                printf("\nThe cost of it will be 40RM for Normal and 70RM for Urgent(type the cost): ");
                scanf("%f", &service_fee);
                break;

            case 3:
                printf("\nThe cost of it will be 330RM for Normal and 430RM for Urgent(type the cost): ");
                scanf("%f", &service_fee);
                break;

            case 4:
                printf("\nThe cost of it will be 160RM for Normal and 200RM for Urgent(type the cost): ");
                scanf("%f", &service_fee);
                break;

            case 5:
                printf("\nThe cost of it will be 180RM for Normal and 210RM for Urgent(type the cost): ");
                scanf("%f",&service_fee);
                break;

            case 6:
                printf("\nThe cost of it will be 50RM for Normal and 80RM for Urgent(type the cost): ",service_fee);
                scanf("%f",&service_fee);
            break;

            case 7:
                printf("\nThe cost of it will be 100RM for Normal and 150RM for Urgent(type the cost): ",service_fee);
                scanf("%f",&service_fee);
            break;

            case 8:
                printf("\nThe cost of it will be 50RM for Normal and 75RM for Urgent(type the cost): ",service_fee);
                scanf("%f",&service_fee);
            break;

            default:
            printf("Invalid option");
          }

          printf("\n\nPayment: ", payment_made);
          scanf("%f",&payment_made);

          if(payment_made > service_fee)
          {
            changes = payment_made - service_fee;
            printf("\nHere is your changes :%.2f\n", changes);
          }
            fclose(Welcome);
}
void Viewing_Store()
{
  FILE *view;
  view = fopen("visitdetails.txt","r");

  printf("No |    Service Type                                    | Needed Days | Service Fee | \n");
  printf("                                                                      |Normal|Urgent|\n");
  printf("1. | Remove virus,Malware, or Spyware                   |      2      | 30RM | 50RM |\n");
  printf("2. | Troubleshot and fix computer running slow          |      2      | 40RM | 70RM |\n");
  printf("3. | Laptop Screen Replacement                          |      3      | 330RM| 430RM|\n");
  printf("4. | Laptop Keyboard Replacement                        |      2      | 160RM| 200RM|\n");
  printf("5. | Laptop Battery Replacement                         |      1      | 180RM| 210RM|\n");
  printf("6. | Operating System Format and Installation           |      2      | 50RM | 80RM |\n");
  printf("7. | Data Backup and Recovery                           |      2      | 100RM| 150RM|\n");
  printf("8. | Internet Connectivity issues                       |      1      | 50RM | 75RM |\n");


  fclose(view);
}
void change_type()
{
  FILE *change;
  char name[20], gender[20], op, option, date[50];
  int visit_ID, phone_number, service_needed, change_service;
  float service_fee, payment_made, changes, change_service_fee;

      change = fopen("visitdetails.txt","r");
      printf("\nAre you sure you want to change the service type into(Y/N) : ", op);
      scanf("%s", &op);
      if(op == 'Y')
      {
        printf("\nWhat service type do you want to change into(1-8)? ", change_service);
        scanf("%d", &change_service);
        switch(change_service)
        {
          case 1:
          printf("\nThe cost of it will be 30RM for Normal and 50RM for Urgent(type the cost): ",change_service_fee);
          scanf("%f",&change_service_fee);
          break;

          case 2:
          printf("\nThe cost of it will be 40RM for Normal and 70RM for Urgent(type the cost): ",change_service_fee);
          scanf("%f",&change_service_fee);
          break;

          case 3:
          printf("\nThe cost of it will be 330RM for Normal and 430RM for Urgent(type the cost): ",change_service_fee);
          scanf("%f",&change_service_fee);
          break;

          case 4:
          printf("\nThe cost of it will be 160RM for Normal and 200RM for Urgent(type the cost): ",change_service_fee);
          scanf("%f",&change_service_fee);
          break;

          case 5:
          printf("\nThe cost of it will be 180RM for Normal and 210RM for Urgent(type the cost): ",change_service_fee);
          scanf("%f",&change_service_fee);
          break;

          case 6:
          printf("\nThe cost of it will be 50RM for Normal and 80RM for Urgent(type the cost): ",change_service_fee);
          scanf("%f",&change_service_fee);
          break;

          case 7:
          printf("\nThe cost of it will be 100RM for Normal and 150RM for Urgent(type the cost): ",change_service_fee);
          scanf("%f",&change_service_fee);
          break;

          case 8:
          printf("\nThe cost of it will be 50RM for Normal and 75RM for Urgent(type the cost): ",change_service_fee);
          scanf("%f",&change_service_fee);
          break;

          default:
          printf("Invalid option");
        }
      }
      else if (op == 'N')
      {
        printf("\nThe final price will be : %.2f", service_fee);
      }

      printf("\n\nPayment: ", payment_made);
      scanf("%f",&payment_made);

      if(payment_made > service_fee)
      {
        changes = payment_made - service_fee;
        printf("\nHere is your changes :%.2f\n", changes);
      }
      else if(payment_made > change_service_fee)
      {
        changes = payment_made - change_service_fee;
        printf("\nHere is your changes: %.2f\n", changes);
      }
      else if(payment_made == service_fee)
      {
        changes = payment_made - service_fee;
        printf("\nHere is your changes %f\n", changes);
      }
      else if(payment_made == change_service_fee)
      {
        changes = payment_made - change_service_fee;
        printf("\nHere is your changes: %f\n", changes);
      }
      else
      {
        printf("Error");
      }

      fprintf(change, "\n\nChanging service type into: %d", change_service);
      fprintf(change, "\nThe price of this service type is: %f", change_service_fee);
      fprintf(change,"\nPayment: %.2f",payment_made);
      fclose(change);
}
void any_visit(char anv[])
{
  FILE *anyvisit;

  char name[200], gender[20],date[50];
  int visit_ID, phone_number, service_needed, change_service, set;
  float service_fee, payment_made, changes, change_service_fee;

  anyvisit = fopen("visitdetails.txt","r");
  while(fscanf(any_visit, "%s %d %s %s %d %d\n", name, visit_ID, date, gender, phone_number, payment_made) !=EOF)
  {
    set = strcmp(date, anv);
    if(set == 0)
    {
      printf("Visit_ID is %d", visit_ID);
      printf("\nName : %s", name);
      printf("\nGender is %s", gender);
      printf("\nPhone number is %d", phone_number);
      printf("\nPayment : %.2f", payment_made);
    }
  }
  fclose(anyvisit);
}
void search(char cnm[])
{
  FILE *search;

  char name[200], gender[20],date[50];
  int visit_ID, phone_number, service_needed, change_service,tes;
  float service_fee, payment_made, changes, change_service_fee;

  search = fopen("visitdetails.txt","r");
  while(fscanf(search, "%s %d %s %s %d %d\n", name, visit_ID, date, gender, phone_number, payment_made) !=EOF)
  {
    tes = strcmp(name, cnm);
    if (tes == 0)
    {
      printf("Visit_ID is %d", visit_ID);
      printf("Date of visit is %s", date);
      printf("\nGender is %s", gender);
      printf("\nPhone number is %d", phone_number);
      printf("\nPayment: %d", payment_made);
    }
  }
  fclose(search);
}

void main()
{
  char name[200], gender[20], op, option, ch, cnm[30], anv[30],date[50];
  int visit_ID, phone_number, service_needed, change_service;
  float service_fee, payment_made, changes, change_service_fee;

  printf("*****Welcome to the Computer center*****\n");
  printf("\nBefore entering the store and have your equipment repair, it is best to view the store\n");
  do
  {
  printf("\nPress '1' to enter and have your data store");
  printf("\nPress '2' to View the store");
  printf("\nPress '3' to have your equipment being repaired");
  printf("\nPress '4' if you want to change your repair type");
  printf("\nPress '5' if you want to Search");
  printf("\nPress '6' if you want to search payment and unpaid balance by any visit");
  printf("\nPress '0' to exit");
  printf("\nEnter your choice : ");
  scanf("%d",&ch);
    switch(ch)
    {
    case 1: entry();
        break;
    case 2: Viewing_Store();
        break;
    case 3: Repair();
        break;
    case 4:change_type();
        break;
    case 5: printf("Enter your name: ");
            scanf("%s", &cnm);
            search(cnm);
        break;
    case 6: printf("Enter the date you visit: ");
            scanf("%d", &anv);
            any_visit(anv);
        break;
    case 0: exit(0);
    default: printf("\nInvalid Entry!!! ");
    }
  } while(ch != 0);
}
```

Comment: This isn't an answer. If you have information to add then edit your question. If you have a question for a user then post a comment on their answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues in the posted code:

- `scanf("%s", &gender);` should be `scanf("%19s", gender);`
- why do you read from `fpointer` in `fscanf(fpointer, "%d", service_needed);` ?
- `strcmp(date, anv);` is invalid as `date` is an `int`.
- `scanf("%s", &op)` is incorrect as `op` is a single `char`. You cannot store a string into it. use `scanf(" %c", &op)` (with an initial space to skip the pending newline).
- it is risky to store phone numbers as integers, some may exceed the range of type `int` and the initial `0` will be lost. Use a string for that.
- the contents you write to **visitdetails.txt** is inconsistent with the way you read from this database. You should just use:

  ```
  printf(any_visit, "%s %d %d %s %d %.2f\n", name, visit_ID, date, gender, phone_number, payment_made);
  ```
- `main` has a return type of `int`.

There are many more mistakes in the code, compiling with warnings enabled, I get **106 warnings** and **1 error**.

You should enable all warnings and let the compiler help you avoid type mismatches and similar bugs: use `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror` and fix all these warnings.